# Pivoting data in MySQL. 

Tags: mysql

I'm sure this sort of question has come up before but I've been searching and can't find anything similar to what I need.

Edit: so after some reading this looks like it falls under pivots and uses group concat. If anybody has any insight id really appreciate it.

I have 3 tables (unnecessary fields & data stripped out for simplicity):

```
Students
id       name
------------------
1        John
2        Jane



Tests
id     name
------------------
1      Test1
2      Test2



Results
id    test_id     student_id   result
--------------------------------------
1     1           1            90
2     1           2            70
3     2           1            50
4     2           2            95
```

What I want is to be able to produce a table like this:

```
Name     Average    Test1    Test2
-----------------------------------
John     70         90        50
Jane     92.5       70        95
```

I know how to get the average, and I'm sure I could do this with an ugly set of loops and php logic but I'd like to get the most efficient solution. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    s.name,
    avg(r.result) AS average,
    t1.result AS test1,
    t2.result AS test2
FROM
    students s,
    results r,
    results t1,
    results t2
WHERE
    r.student_id = s.id AND
    t1.test_id = 1 AND
    t1.student_id = s.id AND
    t2.test_id = 2 AND
    t2.student_id = s.id
GROUP BY s.id;

+------+---------+-------+-------+
| name | average | test1 | test2 |
+------+---------+-------+-------+
| John |      70 |    90 |    50 | 
| Jane |    82.5 |    70 |    95 | 
+------+---------+-------+-------+
```

**Edit:** You can't really make the test columns dynamically based on the contents of the tests table. You can pick specific values to use as columns though.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at the [AVG](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) function.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
mysql> Select s.Name as Name, avg(r.result) as Average 
from result as r join Student as s 
on r.id=s.id group by (r.id)
```

you will have something like this:

```
Name     Average 
-----------------
John     70    
Jane     92.5
```

You can't put a row as a column, imagine that John have 100000 times the test1, it will no be possible to put it as column.

Comment: I've kept searching and  it looks possible. It's something to do with pivot tables and the group concat function.

Comment: @Mcg1978 You can make it dynamic if you create some kind of procedure or function, but remember for each row as column you need a "JOIN" that will affect performance.